# How can i upload a pickle file using curl to get some treatment done

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, curl, pickle

I am trying to upload a pickle file containing some data using curl. I used this command

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -F 'data=@/example_data.p' http://localhost:9999/process
```

This what I have on /process

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        d = request.get_json()
        p = dict(d['payload'])
        print(p.keys())
        # print(p)
        gid = uuid.uuid4()
        Q.put({'gid': gid, 'payload': p})
        print(gid)

        r = {"id": str(gid)}
        response = app.response_class(response=json.dumps(
            r), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        return response
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the error I am getting

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  904k  100   192  100  904k    901  4245k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 4266kHTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 192
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: Werkzeug/2.0.0 Python/3.7.8
Date: Thu, 27 May 2021 01:56:00 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

Can anyone explain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to read a json object (d = request.get_json()) when the data is a pickle file.

You probably want to do something like:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def process():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        d = pickle.loads(request.get_data())
```